# Merging multiple connected columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns

I have two different columns for several samples, which are connected. I want to merge all columns of type 1 to one column and all of type 2 to one column, but the rows should stay connected.

Example:

```
a1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b1 <- c(1, 4, 9, 16, 25)
a2 <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)  
b2 <- c(4, 8, 12, 16, 20)
df1 <- data.frame(a1, b1, a2, b2)

  a1  b1  a2  b2
1 1   1   2   4
2 2   4   4   8
3 3   9   6   12
4 4   16  8   16
5 5   25  10  20
```

I want to have it like this:

```
   a  b 
1  1  1
2  2  4
3  2  4
4  3  9
5  4  8
6  4  16
7  5  25
8  6  12
9  8  16
10 10 20
```

[My case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0TZw.jpg)

This is the example in my case. I have a lot of columns with different names and I want to extract `abs_dist_1, ... abs_dist_5` and `mean_vel_1, ... mean_vel_5` in a new data frame, with all abs_dist in one column and all mean_vel in one column, but still connected.

I tried with `unlist`, but then of course the connection gets lost.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R option using `reshape`

```
subset(
  reshape(
    setNames(df1, gsub("(\\d)", ".\\1", names(df1))),
    direction = "long",
    varying = 1:ncol(df1)
  ),
  select = -c(time, id)
)
```

gives

```
     a  b
1.1  1  1
2.1  2  4
3.1  3  9
4.1  4 16
5.1  5 25
1.2  2  4
2.2  4  8
3.2  6 12
4.2  8 16
5.2 10 20
```

Comment: I reshaped my data frame and created a new subset and then, this works fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` by specifying the `names_sep` as a regex lookaround to match between a lower case letter (`[a-z]`) and a digit in the column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c( '.value', 'grp'), 
       names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])") %>%
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#       a     b
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     2     4
# 3     2     4
# 4     4     8
# 5     3     9
# 6     6    12
# 7     4    16
# 8     8    16
# 9     5    25
#10    10    20
```

---

With the edited post, we need to change the `names_sep` i.e. the delimiter is now `_` between a lower case letter and a digit

```
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c( '.value', 'grp'), 
       names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])_(?=[0-9])") %>%
   select(-grp)
```

---

or with `base R`, use `split.default` on the substring of column names into a `list` of `data.frame`, then `unlist` each `list` element by looping over the `list` and convert to `data.frame`

```
data.frame(lapply(split.default(df1, sub("\\d+", "", names(df1))), 
       unlist, use.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: Okay, in my specific case I have a lot more columns in my data frame and instead of `a1, a2, ...` and `b1, b2, ...`, it's `dist1, dist2, ...` and `vel1, vel2, ...`. In what way do I have to change the command?

Comment: @MDC If the pattern is similar, you don't have to change anything i.e. dist1, dist2, vel1, vel2, etc should work the same as 'a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2' etc.  Please note that I used `everything()` ie. all the columns have this similar pattern.  If it is a subset, then you may need to specify that in `cols =`'

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, that it is a subset within the data frame. How do I specify `cols =` in this case?

Comment: @MDC You can specify either index i..e suppose the columns dist1, to vel10 are from 3 to 10 in position, then use `cols = 3:10` or otherwise, you can also use regex pattern is. `cols = matches('^[A-Za-z]+\\d+$')` i.e. starting with lower or upper case letters followed by one or more digits at the end in column names

Comment: I wrote now `df1 <- G2FFPr %>% pivot_longer(cols = 40:49, names_to = c( '.value', 'grp'), names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])") %>% select(-grp)`, but the output is the whole data frame (G2FFPr).

Comment: @MDC May be you wanted to `select` the columns and then pivot_longer all of them i.e. `df1 <- G2FFPr %>% select(40:49) %>% pivot_longer(..`

Comment: okay, that separates the specific columns, but still, keeps them as they are and not merged.

Comment: you may need to show example.  i answered the question based on ur input eg

Comment: I edited the question, hope this is more specific.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is a solution which uses `data.table::melt()` and the `patterns()` function to specify columns which belong together:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure.vars = patterns(a = "a", b = "b"))[
  order(a,b), !"variable"]
```

> ```
>      a  b
>  1:  1  1
>  2:  2  4
>  3:  2  4
>  4:  3  9
>  5:  4  8
>  6:  4 16
>  7:  5 25
>  8:  6 12
>  9:  8 16
> 10: 10 20
> ```

This reproduces the expected result for OP's sample dataset.

### A more realistic example: reshape only selected columns

With the edit of the question, the OP has clarifified that the production data contains *many more columns* than those which need to be reshaped:

> I have a lot of columns with different names and I want to extract
> `abs_dist_1`, ... `abs_dist_5` and `mean_vel_1`, ... `mean_vel_5` in a new
> data frame, with all `abs_dist` in one column and all `mean_vel` in one
> column, but still connected.

So, the OP wants to *extract and reshape the columns of interest in one go* while ignoring all other data in the dataset.

To simulate this situation, we need a more elaborate dataset which includes other columns as well:

```
df2 <- cbind(df1, c1 = 11:15, c2 = 21:25)
df2
```

> ```
>    a1 b1 a2 b2 c1 c2
> 1  1  1  2  4 11 21
> 2  2  4  4  8 12 22
> 3  3  9  6 12 13 23
> 4  4 16  8 16 14 24
> 5  5 25 10 20 15 25
> ```

With a modified version of the code above

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("a", "b")
result <- melt(setDT(df2), measure.vars = patterns(cols), value.name = cols)[, ..cols]
setorderv(result, cols)
result
```

we get

> ```
>      a  b
>  1:  1  1
>  2:  2  4
>  3:  3  9
>  4:  4 16
>  5:  5 25
>  6:  2  4
>  7:  4  8
>  8:  6 12
>  9:  8 16
> 10: 10 20
> ```

For the production dataset as pictured in the edit, the OP needs to set

```
cols <- c("abs_dist", "mean_vel")
```

Comment: I will test this, thanks. I have no time for this right now, but I will come back to this :)